# Android ignoring maxWidth

Tags: android, size, width, imageview, css

If I try adding 'android:maxWidth="400dp"' to the following ImageView, nothing happens... and ideas?

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/content_background"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/img_background" />
```

Comment: I guess android:layout_width="fill_parent" overrides it?

Comment: Could be... would you have any idea's for a workaround?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone else that encounters this problem: I had to wrap it in a FrameLayout and apply the maxWidth to the FrameLayout as its layout_width. Looks something like:

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="800dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/content_background"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/img_background" />
</FrameLayout>
```

where 800dp == the ImageView's effective 'maxWidth'. This shouldn't interfere on smaller devices, either.

Comment: But this doesn't set the `maxWidth`, in that this approach guarantees the width will be 800dp even when it could be smaller, which is the point of using maxWidth in the first place.